# Single-character winApi textbox

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to do single-character textbox? In other words, after entering 1 character it must not enter other characters that user will be typing;

Comment: which api are you using to create textbox?

Comment: `EM_LIMITTEXT` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761607(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For edit use [EM_LIMITTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or equivalent EM_SETLIMITTEXT) message.
For richedit you need [EM_LIMITTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [EM_EXLIMITTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for text length values greater than 64000

If you use mfc than you need [CEdit::LimitText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95zx4bc4.aspx) or [CRichEditCtrl::LimitText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7xwdbt6b.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can limit length of text in textbox by sending [EM_SETLIMITTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. If you need single character limit :

```
const int maximum_length = 1;
SendMessage(hEdit, EM_SETLIMITTEXT, maximum_length, 0);
```

**note:** *`EM_LIMITTEXT` and `EM_SETLIMITTEXT` are identifiers for the same message. They are constants with same numeric value. Two identifiers exist for historical reasons. (`EM_SETLIMITTEXT` is new from Win95/WinNT 4.0 SDK)*